# aspose.word returns only first table and section

Tags: c#, nuget, docx, aspose

I have office word 2013 .docx file which has plenty of sections and tables.
I don't know why all collection like below return single item while i have many of them in my .docx?

```
  Document document = new Document(filePath);
  int sectionsCount=document.Sections.Count;
  int firstSectionTablesCount=document.FirstSection.Body.Tables.Count;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

it's my fault because i didn't applied licence i got only first table and section id document.

Applying licence:

```
        Aspose.Words.License license=new License();
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic");
```